# Autofac + OWIN + Web Api ASP.NET MVC constructor injection not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

I have a WebApiController with no default constructor and after infoke I receive this error:

```
    <Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'LookupsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()</StackTrace><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>El tipo 'TA.WebApp.MvcApp.Controllers.LookupsController' no tiene un constructor predeterminado</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   en System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
   en System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)</StackTrace></InnerException></Error>
```

This is the configuration invoked from Startup class:

```
public static void ConfigureContainer(IAppBuilder app, Assembly mvcApplicationAssembly)
        {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                var config = new HttpConfiguration();

                builder.RegisterApiControllers(mvcApplicationAssembly).PropertiesAutowired();
                builder.RegisterControllers(mvcApplicationAssembly).PropertiesAutowired();
                builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
                builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
                builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

                builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));

                var container = builder.Build();
                config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
                DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

                app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
                app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
                app.UseWebApi(config);
                app.UseAutofacMvc();
        }
```

I had reviewed the configuration one thousand times and followed the documentation but I can't see the problem.

I have other controller MVC with the same parameter type in constructor and works perfect.

Any help will be very appreciated.

**EDITED:**
This is the code where IRegistration is registered:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
                builder.RegisterType<RegistrationServiceFacade>()
                    .As<IRegistration>();
        }
```

This code is inside an Autofac Module.

Comment: What is the constructor for `LookupsController`?

Comment: A parametrized constructor: "public LookupsController(IRegistration service)..". As I said, I have another MVC controller with the same parameter type in constructor and works well.

Comment: I don't see you setting up `IRegistration` for injections though

Comment: So you have ctor injection working in an MVC controller? Do you have ctor injection working in any WebAPI controller?

Comment: Yes, I have ctor injection working in all MVC controller and I don't have any ctor injection working in WebAPI.

Comment: Some working example will be very appreciated too.

Comment: Can you show your code where you register `IRegistration`?

Comment: I had edited the issue.

Comment: By looking at your stack trace you can see that there is no autofac involved in creating the controller instance. It is using the default resolver. I wonder if you need both of those lines 

app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
app.UseWebApi(config);

or if the order of registration is correct.

Comment: I had followed Autofac Documentation: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration. I know that Autofac is not involved in ApiControllers creation but I have followed all the configuration steps and I have no idea why don't work. I have been looking for an example with Owin+WebApi+Autofac but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Can you get rid of your proprietary code and post a non-working example of your code? I have it exactly like you have it minus your custom module registration and it works fine

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: not yet! Really I haven't tried again